# Is there any javascript library which helps me to create this table layout for viewing, editing, deleting and newing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this kind of table layout once upon a time (Unfortunately, I forget where I had seen this), which enable me to perform viewing, editing, deleting and newing.

[image: Useful table layout]

Note that, click on `Edit` will turn the static label into an editable text field. Pressing `Enter` or `ESC`, with either commit changes to database or cancel the text changes.

1. Do you know any javascript library which enable me to do this?
2. Do you know any web site which employ this kind of user interface? I surf several of Google web site, but unable to find something similar.

Comment: It looks like http://www.ajaxcrud.com/ has something similar to what you're talking about.

Comment: it also could be a asp.net grid view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=5) plugin might be able to do what you need and it even [has its own tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqgrid) on SO. Have a look at the "Row Editing | Using Events" [demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) to see some inline editing.